# Create a React Popup to auth identity providers user ( Linkedin/Facebook/Google)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0

I'm developing a SAAS MVP that relies on identity providers to login the user.
Currently the back end counts with an API(POST /{provider}/auth) that accept redirect_uri and auth_code to exchange it to an identity provider access_token.
To improve user experience i chose the popup strategy instead of the redirect one (which i could easily use to receive an auth code and exchange it with my backend if i would).
So i thought to create a popup by myself that redirect the user to an identity provider authorization page and, after successfully grants the authorizations and redirected the user again, parse the url and catch the auth code asynchronously.
I tried coding something in react but i'm not so experienced with it, could you guys please help me?

```
const CLIENT_ID = '{CLIENT_ID}'

const FacebookLoginPopupButton = ({
    height='600', width='679', apiVersion='15.0', 
    clientId=CLIENT_ID, redirectUri='https://localhost:3000/facebook/auth2/code', state='random_uuid', scope='email',
    onSuccess, onFailure}) => {



    const openNewWindowWithFacebookAuth = (event) => {
        const popup = window.open('https://www.facebook.com/v'+ apiVersion + '/dialog/oauth?' +
            'scope='+ scope + 
            '&client_id=' + clientId + 
            '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri + 
            '&state=' + state + 
            '&response_type=granted_scopes,code' + 
            '&auth_type=rerequest', 
            '_blank', 'height=' + height + ',width=' + width)
    }


    return (
        <div onClick={openNewWindowWithFacebookAuth}>
             <p>Sign in with Facebook</p>
        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly where you're facing an issue? Is it in opening a new pop-up window or the API calls and redirection?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @EternalObserver.
The issue is the latter, i'm not able to finish this flow in react. 
I mean: catch the url change event ( if exists one ) from this window or after the signin flow parse the url, close the popup window and return the data to my component callback.
I don't know if i explained it correctly.